# CSS grid columns not spanning full vertical height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

This is probably a silly question, but I have attempted to recreate a grid with 2 columns, aside on the left and main on the right and the standard one column view on tablet.

However, I am not sure how to properly force the columns in desktop and tablet to be full 100% height. I dont want to use viewport heights.

I am trying to keep the css specifically to the grid way. not sure on the correct way of implementing it though, but I think I am nearly there...
Using css grid for the structure and flexbox for the internals would be what I am aiming for.

```css
/* grid */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* body, html {min-height: 100%; height: 100%} */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}


/* items */

.grid>* {
  color: #353535;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: #d0cfc5;
}

header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* nav styles */

.grid nav {
  background: #136fd2;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #d0cfc5;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* media query for grid layout */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* grid */
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "aside main";
    grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* specific item styles */
  .grid aside {
    grid-area: aside;
  }
  .grid main {
    grid-area: main;
  }
  header {
    display: none;
  }
  /* nav styles */
  nav ul {
    background: #d0cfc5;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  }
  nav li a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header role="banner">
    <h1>Yoko</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <aside>
    <h3>Aside</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>

  <main>
    <div>
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Curabitur orci lacus, auctor ut facilisis nec, ultricies quis nibh.</p>
      <p>Nullam fringilla velit sed porta gravida. Proin eu vulputate libero. Ut a lacinia enim. Etiam venenatis mauris et orci tempor congue. Sed tempor eros et ultricies congue. Aenean sed efficitur orci. Nulla vel tempus mi.</p>

      <p>Ut cursus suscipit augue, id sagittis nibh faucibus eget. Etiam suscipit ipsum eu augue ultricies, at rhoncus mi faucibus. In et tellus vitae leo scelerisque fringilla nec at nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case a good solution is add `grid-template-rows: 100vh` instead `grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);` because you should set up height of one cell in grid.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* grid */
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "aside main";
    grid-template-rows: 100vh;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Of course you could set `height: 100vh` for child element, but you have mentioned you are not going to do it.
What about it? Does it solve the problem?

Comment: I was just thinking there was a better way using grid to get full heights, and I think the grid-template-row is good enough. I do have an issue when I apply it to the 1 column in tablet view, the main text content gets pushed down with the vh, is there a way with flexbox I can make the content sit up higher?

Comment: The advantage of the grid over flex is that the grid gives you the ability to create a two-dimensional grid. Flex gives you the possibility to create content in one line only. So either way you would have to give height to the element. If you want to have a different view for the tablet and a different view for the computer then separate the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'aside header header header '
    'aside main main main  ';
}
.grid > header{
 grid-area: header;
 background-color: red;
 padding: 10px;
}

.grid > aside{ 
 grid-area: aside;
  background-color: yellow;
   padding: 10px;
 
}
.grid > main { 
 grid-area: main;
 padding: 10px;
}



.grid nav {
  background: #136fd2;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #d0cfc5;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  nav ul {
    background: #d0cfc5;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  }
  nav li a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header role="banner">
    <h1>Yoko</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <aside>
    <h3>Aside</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>

  <main>
    <div>
      <h2>Article</h2>
      <p>Curabitur orci lacus, auctor ut facilisis nec, ultricies quis nibh.</p>
      <p>Nullam fringilla velit sed porta gravida. Proin eu vulputate libero. Ut a lacinia enim. Etiam venenatis mauris et orci tempor congue. Sed tempor eros et ultricies congue. Aenean sed efficitur orci. Nulla vel tempus mi.</p>

      <p>Ut cursus suscipit augue, id sagittis nibh faucibus eget. Etiam suscipit ipsum eu augue ultricies, at rhoncus mi faucibus. In et tellus vitae leo scelerisque fringilla nec at nunc.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think you have understood my question

Comment: what you desire ?

Comment: Im asking for 100% vertical heights for my columns, your columns example does not even extend top to bottom. I think I fixed it for the -- desktop mode: grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr) and min-height: 100vh -- the tablet mode: height: 100vh.

Comment: `aside`  column will be top to bottom 100vh ?